# How to store log files of a shell script in HDFS

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have shell script in `HDFS`. I want to collect the logs for this script in HDFS only.

The contents of the script are below:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

hdfs dfs -touchz /user/$USER/logs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log

hdfs dfs -touchz /user/$USER/logs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

success_logs=/user/$USER/logs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log

failed_logs=/user/$USER/logs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log


function log_status
{
   status=$1
   message=$2
   if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
            #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
            exit 1
            else
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
            fi
}
```

The logs are not appending to the files. only the files are being created.

How can I get the files to have the result of the function to be appended in `HDFS`

Comment: Why not write them in local first and finally upload to HDFS?

Comment: This is going to be shell action right? If that is the case, you can very well create the logfile in local filesystem.

Comment: Yes, in local Filesystem. Do you get an exception otherwise? Anyway I will provide solution to append a file in HDFS. Final call is yours to make. You can either write the log in Local and upload it to HDFS in the end, or append to the logfile directly in HDFS. I prefer the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The logs are not appending to the files. only the files are being
>   created.

Because `tee` is a linux command and does not work for files stored in HDFS.

Use [`-appendToFile`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile)

```
echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | hdfs dfs -appendToFile - ${failed_logs}
```

`-` in place of `srcfile` is to read the input from stdin.